# Installing jest & vue test utils manually no - trouble with import

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am trying to install vue-test-utils and jest in a project. It is vue-cli project but I did not setup the testing when I ran it initially.

It finds the test but fails on the import statements.

Here is the error.

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

   This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

   By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
```

It is almost certainly a babel thing (I think) but I cannot work it out.

Here are the config files.

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-serializer-vue'
  ],
  testMatch: [
    '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
  ],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/'
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-moment": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.6.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.6.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.6.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a working configuration?  I'm trying to set up unit tests as well but running into issue with both mocha and jest.  Initially it was an ES6 compat issue, but then I hit a dead-end with a parser error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697023/how-do-i-configure-mocha-to-run-with-vue-js).  Going to take another run at jest...  Thanks.

Comment: I did I can't  remember what I did though, will dig it out and post it

Comment: I'm getting the same thing in NUXT VueJs project with Jest. How di you fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you need `global` section in your jest config. I'm using vue + ts, so my globals looks like that:

```
globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
        babelConfig: true
    }
}
```